# See original file on the web of Rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to see this and another files of the rails 3.2.8 by the browser on the web.

actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb

I know the GitHub has railsdoc but I don't know which the version that is.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb

Comment: expanding on Mischa's comment, you can always select a particular branch and tag on github.  the dropdown is located on the left side of the Files tab so you're not limited to a specific version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is available for public consumption [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb)

When looking for files on github, just make sure you have the right tag set, see the image below:

[image]